# ViewModel in Java (Spring)

Tags: java, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-mvc, viewmodel

I've read much about the usage of ViewModel in ASP.Net MVC, and in fact used the pattern myself.

Now that I'm looking at MVC in Java (specifically using the Spring framework), it doesn't seem to get any attention.

What is the reason for that?

Is there some other mechanism which is more suitable for Java?

(The idea of course is to separate the core Models of the application from some ViewModel which is more View specific)

Comment: It *does* get attention, you're probably not tuned to the many channels. Spring MVC is a great way to proceed in general.

Comment: I'd really appreciate it if you could point me to some discussion or blog post about the usage of ViewModel in Spring MVC.

Comment: There is no ViewModel, but there are corresponding classes. Read more about it on http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html